# What design concept am I dealing with?

Tags: firebase, design-patterns, architecture

I have two data objects- `customers` and `jobs`. Job records are created based on certain fields of the customer record. A job record is created for each service visit to the customer, which happens on a recurring weekly basis.

So I'm considering the best way to create job records, I can either:

1. Use a server function to create job records on the backend. And create them in batches- say, quarterly- so I'd have job records for 12 weeks ahead. This way I can just query the `jobs` table for any operations in the presentation layer.
2. Use fields on the `customers` table to create jobs in the presentation layer, creating the `job` record only after some interaction with the presentation layer.
   This way, jobs are always created from updated data.

I think I should go with the second approach but it seems like I might be committing a design transgression when it comes to handling data and presentation layers.

Is there some concept that encapsulates this type of problem?

--

Drawback to first approach: The server function would have to run after any changes to the customer record so that jobs are updated. I suppose I could schedule the function to run every night (cron job) so I'm getting updated records every day. But I think there should be a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of an opinion question, and I suspect it might get removed.

but, I would go with #2, always.  with #1 you're creating a lot of empty data records that hold no value and may or may not get used.  It also gives you an opportunity to present the data to the user for verification before saving the job.

Comment: Thanks @teacurran I suspected creating the records first was a bad idea